# Policy/rule for a question to be removed

Tags: discussion, reputation, deleted-posts

Losing 20 points just because I answered a question that was marked as "removed" is not a big deal. I have read about the question deletion/removal in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions). I appreciate very well that there are policies/rules/norms set up by Stack Overflow which everyone should obey and pay attention to.

The question I am talking about, [Where to Find High Quality Online Video Training for Developing with Apple Technologies (Mac OS X, iPhone, etc)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173481/where-to-find-high-quality-online-video-training-for-developing-with-apple-techn), is still [available in Google's cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:lqj3cs_k6TgJ:stackoverflow.com/questions/3173481/where-to-find-high-quality-online-video-training-for-developing-with-apple-techn+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=au).

What I do not understand is why a question such as the removed should affect the reputation of someone who genuinely spent time thinking and preparing the answer. Even though there are newer iOS developer resources, some of them mentioned in the question are classics and they are still relevant. Above all, just having a "Removed" mark next to a question doesn't really make sense, a little note from the person who removed the question definitely helps.

Comment: Well... if your answer was at +3, you would have retained all the reputation gained. But it didn't get there (although it was almost three years old), and I'm afraid there's nothing anyone can do about that.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Not considering the points, it would help if the question was marked as "Archived" or a note added by the person who removed it. It is fine if SO doesn't want questions that do not add value to the topic to be available in search results, etc. I am glad I found this out today after being a member for the last several years.

Comment: @indyfromoz: The question was closed as not constructive and removed moments later (after receiving a spam answer which brought it to the attention of moderators) because it just asks for recommendations, and that kind of question simply is not acceptable on the site. The fact that it survived for so long does not make it an acceptable question for Stack Overflow. It never did belong on the site; it just took a long time to remove it.

Comment: @animuson Thank you for sharing the details. I have immense respect for the moderators and the time they spend in moderating the questions & answers. Without them, SO and other sites in the StackExchange network would not be what they are today. Spamming a question is definitely unacceptable and should not be allowed.

Comment: @indyfromoz `it would help if the question was marked as "Archived"` Well, it is not permanently deleted. Users with over 10000 reputation can see it (like me), and they can vote to undelete it.

Answer (score 6):

Reputation earned for a question that doesn't belong on the site is a temporary thing. You never really should have had it, because the question shouldn't have been here. So you had the rep for a while, but then the question, and the rep, go away.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do not quite understand the first and second sentences. The question I am referring was marked as "Removed" in my reputation which means the question did belong to the site, it was asked by a user. All I am trying to understand is the reason behind the removal of the question.

Comment: @indyfromoz: Yes, it was asked by a user. That doesn't mean it *should* have been asked. The question was deleted specifically because we *don't* allow those questions. And when they get asked, they get deleted.

Comment: @NicolBolas Thank you. I understand there are moderators checking the questions and I very much appreciate the quality of the questions and answers posted. It just surprised me that a question that was asked three years ago is now gone. I agree the question probably didn't add lot of value to the standards of SO.

Comment: @NicolBolas - In this case, I think it was more that the question was asked at a time when we permitted "What is the best resource to learn X" type questions. Heck, I answered this one when it was asked three years ago. We've of course found that these don't work well here, and the two instances of spam answers there finally brought that to our attention. I think all of the links in my answer were dead, even, so I'm not upset that I lost reputation from it being deleted.